# FileHandle возвращает несуществующий файл

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Мне нужно прочитать часть бинарного файла в моей игре на движке libgdx. Файл как положено лежит в папке assets. У меня уже написана реализация через dataInputStream, и я хотел получить через fileHandle inputStream для создания dataInputStream. Это не сработало, тогда я проверил существование файла `fileHandle.exists()`, он возвращает true, получил через него файл `file = fileHandle.file()` и проверил `file.exists()`, он возвращает false. В файле bulid.gradle(:android) прописал

```
aaptOptions {
noCompress "fileName"
    }
```

Так что проблем с упаковкой быть не должно. Как мне получить работающий inputStream?

Comment: На десктопе работает?

Comment: Не знаю, я уже переписал код, не могу проверить.